# Questions on ornaments

Tags: discussion

I would just like to tell the community that question regarding ornaments and the correct interpretation thereof are really hard to answer in a concrete, definitive manner.

When the Oxford Companion to music has a whole chapter dedicated to ornaments and prefaces it by telling you that the best they can do is an overview and that there can very easily be written whole books on the subject it goes to tell how broad such topics really are.

If the standard for a question that is too broad is "Whether you can imagine a whole book being written on the subject." Then I would say ornament interpretation fits the bill perfectly.

Like to hear the community's thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you, but when it comes to a question about one specific ornamentation then I think we're OK. There will certainly be multiple correct answers of some degree of subjectivity, but an expert can give a broadly useful overview and give some guidelines for the asker's own interpretation. I think we have a number of good questions about ornamentation.

Comment: OK but is a question with more than one correct answer a good question to begin with?

Comment: @NeilMeyer Absolutely. The vast majority of questions will involve some degree of opinion, like [most of our top questions](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes), so what's "correct" is not the only metric to consider. Do you have any specific issues with existing questions? As a random example I would think that [these answers](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/29150/28) are very helpful, despite being very different. Neither technique is the one true answer, so it is left to the OP to experiment and decide for themselves which is *excellent*. Teach a man to fish, and all that.

Comment: OK thank you Mr Read if this site's moderators are happy that these types of questions are not too opinion based then I will accept it.